# Trying to make enums work, how do I do it? - CS8803 - C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, computer-science

So I've been trying to use enums for this compsci class I'm taking, yet I keep getting this error, even though I feel like this should work, it doesn't. Why? The error im getting.

"error cs8803 top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations"

```
public enum Ovi {Lukossa, Kiinni, Auki};

public Ovi tila = Ovi.Lukossa;
Console.WriteLine(tila);
```

Comment: You didn't include the error you're getting in your question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs8803

Answer (score 0):

The user Klaus linked me to this, which helped me solve the issue
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs8803

Final product:

```
Ovi tila = Ovi.Lukossa;
Console.WriteLine(tila);
public enum Ovi { Lukossa, Kiinni, Auki };
```

Comment: F1 on the error message also would have directed you to this page, BTW.